# What is the apex for the parabola $y^2+py=px-2p$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Formula: $y^2+py=px-2p$ For which value (s) of $p$
>
> 1. is the apex of the parabola on the line $y = x$
> 2. is the parabola at the right side of the $y$-axis?

$y^2+py=px-2p$ can be written as
$$(y+(1/2p))^2-(1/4p)^2=p(x-2)$$
But how do I get to the correct form?

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging we get $$\left(y+\frac p2\right)^2=px-2p+\frac{p^2}4=4\cdot\frac p4\left(x-\overline{\underbrace{2-\frac p4}}\right)$$

Now the vertex of $$(y-\beta)^2=4a(x-\alpha)$$ is $(\alpha,\beta)$